# Integral with 4 branch points

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

Inspired by [Ron Gordon's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940298/principal-value-of-carlson-elliptic-integral-r-c)  I attempted to integrate
$$
g(w)=h(w)\ln w=\frac{\ln w}{(w+p)\sqrt{(w+x)(w+y)(w+z)}}, \quad (x,y,z,-p>0)
$$
over the contour $\gamma$ shown below.

[image]

> Description of the contour

Line segment joining $P_{k},P_{j}$ is denoted by $L_{k,j}$. Each line segment is parallel to and at a distance $\delta$ from the real line. Small circle centered at $-\alpha$ is denoted by $C_\alpha$ and has radius $r_\alpha$. The large circle centered at $0$ has radius $R$ and is denoted by $C_R$.

We shall consider the limiting case where
      $$\begin{align}&r_\alpha\to0,\quad \alpha=0,x,y,z,p\\
  &R\to+\infty\\&\delta\to0\end{align}$$

> Question

Integrals over $C_\alpha(\alpha=x,y,z,0), C_R$ vanish. Integral over $C_p$ can be computed using residue but
**how can the branch cuts be defined so that $g$ remains continuous inside the contour?**

Comment: Mathematica for the contour drawing?

Comment: @RonGordon I used GeoGebra because I'm too lazy to mathematically represent the contour :)